# How to get location (lat & long) sent by user from Facebook messenger bot through Dialog Flow?

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a emergency chatbot in dialogflow that can get the location of the user.

[image: my custom paload]

[image: sample talks]

So what I'm trying to achieve is to get the Latitude and Longitude from that location like how and store it in variable like this

```
var lat = latitude
var long = longitude
```

Comment: Hey, Treber, please [edit] your question to include a clear problem statement and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get information from webhook event in payload.coordinates property

reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom follw-up intent with event input called FACEBOOK_LOCATION, then the lat and lng is set in context facebook_location, you can print this in a dialwoflow response with "lat: #facebook_location.lat, long: #facebook_location.long"

Image example:

[image]